# How can I get current Office Windows account email using VBA?

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-office

How can I get current Office Windows account email using VBA code?
I do not mean the account which the user is logged in the Windows, I mean the account that is authorized in office

**See image:**
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Office applications don't provide such information via their object models.

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev Can i see the confirmation of this information? (msdn or something else)

Comment: Try to come in from the opposite side - are you able to find anything about that in MSDN? ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can access it.  Your best bet is linking Access to Outlook and trying to access it from there.

For example you Set a reference to the Outlook object library and then :-

```
Dim olook As Outlook.Application
Dim EAddress As String

Set olook = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
Set olook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")


EAddress = olook.Session.CurrentUser.Address
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar solution calling out to Outlook, I'm using Excel and found a way to do this, I've only ever found one address in the Accounts collection, but have a suffix match to try and catch the @company.com I'm looking for:

```
Dim NameSpace As Object
Dim strEmailAddress As String
Set NameSpace = CreateObject("Outlook.Application").GetNameSpace("MAPI")
strEmailAddress = ""

For Each Account In NameSpace.Accounts
    If LCase(Split(Account.SMtpAddress, "@")(1)) = "contoso.com" Then
        strEmailAddress = Account.SMtpAddress
    Else
        strEmailAddress = "Unknown"
    End If

    ' If you want to see more values, uncomment these lines
    'Debug.Print Account.DisplayName
    'Debug.Print Account.UserName
    'Debug.Print Account.SMtpAddress
    'Debug.Print Account.AccountType
    'Debug.Print Account.CurrentUser
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Outlook interrupts the VBA-execution (to access Outlook objects from macro) due to security.

**Snap shot**
[Outlook Security](https://i.stack.imgur.com/21Sxe.jpg)

Hence only to get eMailID without opening  object as well as handling error in case of non availability of outlook/account, following code can work in your case

**VBA Code**

```
Sub Email_Address()
    Dim MAPI As Object

    Status = "unknown"

    On Error GoTo return_value
    Set MAPI = CreateObject("Outlook.Application").GetNameSpace("MAPI")

    i = 1
    Do While True
        Debug.Print MAPI.Accounts.Item(i)
        i = i + 1
    Loop

return_value:
    If i > 1 Then: Status = "done..."
    Debug.Print Status
End Sub
```